# When to return an Item if I don't know when the spider will finish?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

So my spider takes in a list of websites, and it crawls through each one via `start_requests` which `yield` `request` passing in `item` as `meta`.

Then, the spider explores all the internal links of a single website and collects all the external links into the `item`. The problem is that I don't know when the spider finishes crawling all the internal links, so I can't `yield` an `item`.

```
class WebsiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "web"

    def start_requests(self):
        filename = "websites.csv"
        requests = []
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
                reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                header = next(reader)
                for row in reader:
                    seed_url = row[1].strip()
                    item = Links(base_url=seed_url, on_list=[])
                    request = Request(seed_url, callback=self.parse_seed)
                    request.meta['item'] = item
                    requests.append(request)
            return requests
        except IOError:
            raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("A list of websites are needed")

    def parse_seed(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        netloc = urlparse(item['base_url']).netloc
        external_le = LinkExtractor(deny_domains=netloc)
        external_links = external_le.extract_links(response)
        for external_link in external_links:
            item['on_list'].append(external_link)

        internal_le = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=netloc)
        internal_links = internal_le.extract_links(response)

        for internal_link in internal_links:
            request = Request(internal_link, callback=self.parse_seed)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request
```

Comment: Can you show your current code of the spider? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the `start_requests` method needs to yield `Request` objects. You don't need to return a list of requests, but only yield a Request when it is ready, this works because scrapy requests are asynchronous.

The same happens with items, you just need to yield your items whenever you think the item is ready, I would recommend for your case to just check if there are no more `internal_links` to yield the item, or also you can as many items as you want, and then check which one was the last (or the one with more data):

```
class WebsiteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "web"

    def start_requests(self):
        filename = "websites.csv"
        requests = []
        try:
            with open(filename, 'r') as csv_file:
                reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
                header = next(reader)
                for row in reader:
                    seed_url = row[1].strip()
                    item = Links(base_url=seed_url, on_list=[])
                    yield Request(seed_url, callback=self.parse_seed, meta = {'item'=item})
        except IOError:
            raise scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider("A list of websites are needed")

    def parse_seed(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        netloc = urlparse(item['base_url']).netloc
        external_le = LinkExtractor(deny_domains=netloc)
        external_links = external_le.extract_links(response)
        for external_link in external_links:
            item['on_list'].append(external_link)

        internal_le = LinkExtractor(allow_domains=netloc)
        internal_links = internal_le.extract_links(response)
        if internal_links:
            for internal_link in internal_links:
                request = Request(internal_link, callback=self.parse_seed)
                request.meta['item'] = item
                yield request
        else:
            yield item
```

another thing you could do is create an [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#writing-your-own-extension) to do what you need on the `spider_closed` method and do whatever you want knowing when the spider ended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about yielding when internal links run out, but as you mentioned, since scrapy runs asynchronously, even if that certain webpage does not have any internal links, some other webpages might be on the queue waiting to be processed. I have rebuilt the scrapy with the item loader, and I think I might just make a new function that takes in a dictionary and output it to JSON once `closed` is called.

Comment: perfect, so you going with creating your own extension right? I think it is the best, also yielding items at all moments, could help you log how the spider is working, I was doing something similar before.

Comment: You might have to educate me on this issue, but I don't really understand the benefits of using extension. From what I read, it just sounds like implementing a Python class or a function? What I am trying to do is return a JSON when the spider completes crawling through all the seed websites, and I think [`closed`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=closed#scrapy.spiders.Spider.closed) method handles that, so I would need to just implement JSON exporter that would be called once `closed` is called.